# Finding percentile given distance between two percentiles.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, actuarial-science, percentile

The sales for a company are normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The difference between the $90$th and $40$th percentile is $500$. The $70$th percentile is $1700$. What is the $60$th percentile?

I'm not quite sure how to proceed. [Subsequent to comment, see OP answer.]

Answer (score 1):

You need to formulate several equations in several unknowns, and
then solve. For now, I'll try to get you started without just
giving the solution. Use the fact that $Z = (x - \mu)/\sigma$ has a
standard normal distribution. I think this is fundamentally a
question on using tables of the standard normal distribution.

From "The 70th percentile is 1700," one can see that
$$P\{X \le 1700\} = P\{Z \le (1700 - \mu)/\sigma\}= 0.7$$
But also $P\{Z \le 0.5244\} = 0.7$ from tables, so $(1700 - \mu)/\sigma = 0.5244$
is one of your equations.

With that clue in mind, please try so show some progress toward another equation, and maybe
a solution. Most of us on
this site resist posting answers to homework problems without
some participation from the student.

Comment: Thanks. I usually post some attempt but I simply had no idea without the standard deviation.

Comment: OK, but are you making progress now?

Comment: Yes I think I have found the result. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First,

$Pr( Z\leq\frac{\pi_{.9}-\mu}{\sigma})=.9\rightarrow \frac{\pi_{.9}-\mu}{\sigma} = .1285$

$Pr( Z\leq\frac{\pi_{.4}-\mu}{\sigma})=.4 \rightarrow \frac{\pi_{.4}-\mu}{\sigma} = -.25$

$\Large \frac{\pi_{.9}-\mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\pi_{.4}-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{\pi_{.9}-\pi_{.4} }{\sigma}$ = $.3785 \rightarrow .3785\sigma = 500 \rightarrow \sigma = 1321.004$

Then,

$\large \frac{1700 - \mu}{1321.004} =$ $.5244 \rightarrow \mu = 1007.266$

Finally,

$\large \frac{\pi_{.6}-1007.266}{1321.004}$ $= .255 \rightarrow \pi_{.6} = 1344.122$

Comment: Promising, but doesn't seem quite right. In R, the code `qnorm(.9)` returns  1.281552, not .1285. R uses more decimal places than you can get from tables, but this is too far off. Suggest you check values. However, `qnorm(.4)` gives a result consistent with -.25. So you're on the right general track.

Comment: So the process is correct, but the z-score for the 90th percentile is incorrect?

Comment: The general flow looks fine. The z--score for the 40th percentile is OK. The z-score for the 90th percentile is wrong, and errors propagate from there, so I did not check the rest of the numbers (dinner, digesting, etc., etc.) You are getting practice dealing with normal tables (or software), and I suspect that's the main point. I'm sure you can get it. Maybe I can look at in the morning btw mtgs, or someone else will give a nudge.